# Preform sql query programatically in php script to write totals to excel file

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have a pretty straight forward MySQL query that works properly, and I have it in a scheduled PHP script. Currently, It selects the data I need and writes it to a CSV.

This is something I've done quite a few times before, but I now need to do something that I've not done before. I need to change this to write to an excel file and I need to add a 'Total' or 'Sum' row to the file for each user.

Currently it pulls this data for CSR agents and it will display every single record for the day for each agent, so I would need to insert totals for each user after their daily records.

I'm wondering how I can change this query to use PHP variables possibly, and store the data so that I can insert totals for each user at the end of their records. I don't know how possible this is or how it should be done, but I would also be changing format from CSV to XSLX(excel) which may help in terms of how to do this programatically. .

So instead of the current format:

```
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |       |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |       |   10
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |       |       |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |       |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |       |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |       |   x   |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |       |   x   |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
```

I need to do this:

```
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |       |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |       |   10
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      John  |   Doe   |       |       |   10
      ---------------------------------------
      John Doe Totals |   4   |   4   |   60

      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |       |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |       |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |       |   x   |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |       |   x   |   10
      Jane  |   Doe   |   x   |   x   |   10
      ---------------------------------------
      Jane Doe Totals |   4   |   4   |   60
```

Here's the query and CSV code:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn2,
    " SELECT
        FirstN
        , LastN
        , Info1
        , Info2
        , Duration

        FROM (
          SELECT distinct
           firstn
           , lastn
           , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Info1
           , case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Info2
           , b.duration as Time


          FROM session a
                INNER JOIN callsummary b ON a.callID = b.callID
                right join users u on a.callingpartyno = u.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = u.extension
                LEFT JOIN known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
            left join known_numbers kn on a.finallycalledpartyno = kn.long_number
                    WHERE a.ts >= curdate()
                    and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from ambition_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from ambition_users))
          ) x
      order by extension;") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));

if (!$result2) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result2);
$headers = array();
while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result2)) {
  $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
}
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
if ($fp && $result2) {
  fputcsv($fp, $headers);
  while ($row = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: To add totals, you could simply just do a preliminary loop on them all to build an array of data which you then dump to the file after that loop. Given how complex your SQL query is already, doing group by and trying to get the total as an additional column may prove headache worthy.

Comment: Are you trying to explicitly calculate the totals yourself and have those totals the output literally? Or are you trying to create a spreadsheet that has formulas, and those formulas will calculate the totals within Excel?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Honestly, whichever is easiest. I've been doing it manually by putting this CSV in excel and using formulas to calculate totals but my idea was to use php and programatically build the totals in there before writing to the file. I'm not sure what would be more conducive to what I need and the structure of the query.

Comment: It would be somewhat easier to build a CSV with the pre-calculated totals. Given that, there would be no need to actually make it a native Excel file.

Comment: I see, that makes sense then. What would be the best away to build the calculations in the CSV do you think?

Comment: As you iterate over the rows, keep variables with the totals for each column. Then watch for changes to name (or whatever your unique field is) as you write out the loop. When the value in the current row is different than the value in the last row, write an additional line with the totals and then zero the totals for the next person.